# Unable to paste from Windows clipboard into Ubuntu Nano via PuTTY

Tags: linux, ubuntu, putty, clipboard

I cannot find a way to paste into **nano** editor.

I am connecting from Windows Server 2016 via **Putty/SSH** to a remote Linux Ubuntu server and I cannot find a way to paste text from my Windows' clipboard into PuTTY while **nano** is open.

Does anyone know how why this is not working as expected? And what can be done to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

In PuTTY configuration:

- Window → Selection → Shift overrides application's use of mouse

Enable it, apply; then use <kbd>Shift</kbd> + right* mouse click.

<sub>*Or middle mouse click, it depends on other settings there.</sub>

Comment: It was enabled all along. Would disabling it make any difference?

Comment: @Perovic What happens when you Shift+Rclick in `nano`? I believe this is the mode Martin was talking about: as long as you can type, PuTTY will "type" your clipboard content.

Answer (score 0):

This might be a long shot, but you can also paste content with <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Insert</kbd>.